# Remove [] from autogenerated type in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I am provided a type from autogenerated typings, e.g. `Definitions[]`.

My function takes in a single definition of type Definition as an argument.

```
function isDefinition(d: Definition)
```

How can I remove the `[]` from `Definition[]` here?

I am new to typescript missing the right terminology to find a solution.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an array has type `Definition[]`, then its element has type `Definition`. Just like `array[0]` gives an element of an array, `Type[0]` gives the element type of an array:

```js
type Given = Definition[]

type Wanted = Given[0]  // Given = Definition
```